# Encoding/decoding issue of web content

Tags: c#, encoding, decode

It seems like I'm having an issue with encoding/decoding with the website content I'm processing. I'm pulling an XML file from the web and it may have like French and German characters with the little apostrophes on tom of "e" "r", etc, but most of the content is in English. When I try to process them by selecting all the distinct words, sometimes there are duplicates saved into the database. Is there any encoding/decoding class/library that I should be using so that all the words are uniform in one encoding/decoding? I think in my case, even though the words are in English, it seems like the two similar words are in different encoding and the C# equality operator `==` is not matching those two because of different encoding?

So in other words `"car" == "car"` may not match because of encoding? Is this even possible? How should I fix it? Should I decode everything by using?

Update: the code: The below code will check if the word exists, if it is it pulls it else inserts a new word. Therefore should be always distinct words going into database.

```
public static int GetWordID(string word)
{
    string _truncatedword = String.Empty;

    if (word.Length > 48)
    {
        _truncatedword = word.Substring(0, 47).Trim().ToLower();
    }
    else
    {
        _truncatedword = word.Trim().ToLower();
    }

    if (DWords.ContainsKey(_truncatedword))
    {
        return DWords[_truncatedword];
    }
    else
    {
        using (SqlConnection _connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            _connection.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter _adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select wordid from word where word = @word", _connection);
            _adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", _truncatedword);

            DataTable _dtWord = new DataTable();
            _adapter.Fill(_dtWord);

            if (_dtWord.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                int _wordID = Convert.ToInt32(_dtWord.Rows[0]["wordid"]);

                DWords.Add(_truncatedword, _wordID);

                return _wordID;
            }
            else
            {
                SqlCommand _command = new SqlCommand("insert into word(word) values(@word); select @@identity", _connection);
                _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", _truncatedword);

                int _wordID = Convert.ToInt32(_command.ExecuteScalar());

                DWords.Add(_truncatedword, _wordID);

                return _wordID;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example?

Comment: It is pretty basic. I was trying not to insert articles like "the", "a", "an" to the database, but that was inserted after the C# `word != "the"` was checked. So in other words the `word != "the"` failed. The code ran in a single thread without any interruption.

Comment: yes it is possible, there are letters that look like other letter but aren't however from your description above it sounds like you are doing some sort of reference comparison, please post your code.

Comment: from what I understand, you are comparing two similar looking word that has different set of Unicode characters. For all practical programming purposes these words are considered different. You can investigate the two words that you call as duplicate by looking at the contents of each of their char array and I think that will explain it to you.

Comment: I posted the code. Please provide code samples to fix this issue. I'm pretty new to encoding. I want uniform distinct words, not duplicates showing up sometimes. I processed like 50,000 words, and there were like 500 duplicates, so it is not a lot.